# I need each row of the table is separate and can be clickable and view some information. It is possible to be hundreds of rows entered by the users

Tags: javascript, input, html-table, row

```
//input field where user submit data into mysql database and immediately it shows in table
    <form name="form" action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="pitanje" class="search-input" placeholder="Pitajte..." />
    <input class="search-btn" type="submit" value="Go" />
    </form>

<table class='table'>
<tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Question</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Like</th>
    <th>Views</th>
    <th>Answer??</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Question</td>
    <td>Date</td>
    <td>Views</td>
    <td>Like</td>
    <td>
        <button>Press</button>
    </td>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Best example of that is http://www.incredibox.com/top-50 try to click on some row and you will see. Every row

Comment: <A href="www.google.com">And your question is?</A>

Comment: How to make every row of table expandable? Similar to this site that I mentioned as an example...

Comment: Probably a few ways, but the obvious one is an onclick on the TR tag.